# How to count number of rows, when FlexBoxLayoutManger set as layoutManager for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I am using `FlexboxLayoutManager` as:

```
FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

Now I have to inflate items in `recyclerView` and if number of items taking more than 2 rows, then I have to show "Show More" option as last item in second row itself. How can I achieve this?

Each row contains different number of items, i.e. columns may vary as per items length, thats why using FlexBoxLayoutManager.

Comment: did you get any solution for getting row and column count?

Comment: @Ajeet didn't get it.

Answer (score 3):

try it

```
        flexBoxLayoutManager.flexLines.size
```

Comment: It's empty always